# Does angular add `#/` part to the url automatically

Tags: angularjs

I was under impression that when a user hits a website without specifying `#/` at the end, i.e. `mysite.com` as opposed to `mysite.com/#/`, and angular is run in `html5Mode(false)`, the framework is supposed to add hashbang `#/` to the URL automatically. However, in my application it doesn't happen. Is my assumption wrong? Or maybe I've configured something to prevent this.

Comment: Well, you have just proved it wrong, haven't you?

Comment: I'm not so sure, since it does add this hashbang for local file URLs like this `file:///C:/Users/dla/Desktop/test.html`

Comment: Are you saying it behaves differently when loading from the file system? What happens when loading test.html from a HTTP server?

Comment: Yes, it behaves differently because this function `this.$$path = removeWindowsDriveName(this.$$path, withoutHashUrl, appBase);` sets `$$path` to "/" when loaded from filesystem, and to empty string when URL doesn't contain windows drive name. `this.$$path` is then used to decide whether to add hashbang in `this.$$compose = function() {` inside `LocationHashbangUrl` function

Comment: So, you just answered your own question, haven't you?

Comment: @JBNizet, yeah, probably, I just wanted to confirm if my research of source code correct :)

Answer (score 0):

if you try to reach your main page on `mysite.com` with html5mode enable or not, browser doesn't need `#/`. Whereas if you try to reach login page for example with html5mode disabled Angular will automatically rewrite the URL like that : `mysite.com/#/login`.